# Controlling poll frequency of browser.wait() (Fluent Wait)

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

**The Story:**

In Java selenium language bindings there is a [`FluentWait` class](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html), that allows to tightly control how the expected condition would be checked:

> Each FluentWait instance defines the maximum amount of time to wait
>   for a condition, as well as the frequency with which to check the
>   condition. Furthermore, the user may configure the wait to ignore
>   specific types of exceptions whilst waiting, such as
>   NoSuchElementExceptions when searching for an element on the page.

In other words, it's possible to change the polling interval in which the expected condition check is applied, which is by default 500ms. Plus, it's possible to set exceptions to ignore.

It is [also possible in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727340/javas-fluentwait-in-python), there are relevant `poll_frequency` and `ignored_exceptions` arguments to `WebDriverWait` class.

**The Question:**

Is it possible to control the *poll frequency* in which the expected condition is verified when using `browser.wait()` in Protractor/WebDriverJS?

---

According to the [`browser.wait()` documentation](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait), there are only 3 possible arguments: a function which is an expected condition, a timeout value and an optional timeout error message. I hope there is a different setting or way to change the poll frequency.

Comment: From [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#L657) it looks like JS will poll as fast as it can. So basically I don't think it has the parameter you want. But I guess 2 possible workarounds could be:
1. Write a custom `Condition`, that internally sleeps if condition is not true before it returns
2. Construct `Promise` instead, which behaves differently according to the same docs
3. Third option is to rewrite `wait` or wrap it in some custom function. Not a nice option though.

Comment: @KirilS. made some more research and summarized your point in an answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the help of @Kirill S., after the further research and inspecting the [`WebdriverJS` source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#L657), I can conclude that **there is no such thing as "poll frequency" in javascript selenium bindings**. The interval between subsequent condition check calls cannot be configured - it performs the check as quick as possible.

*This is not the same as in, for instance Python or Java selenium bindings*, where there is a configurable timeout between the expected condition state checks. By default, [it would wait for 500ms before the next check](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits):

> *WebDriverWait by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500
>   milliseconds* until it returns successfully. A successful return is for
>   ExpectedCondition type is Boolean return true or not null return value
>   for all other ExpectedCondition types.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to the docs which I read, there doesn't seem to be an actual method that mirrors the functionality of the `FluentWait`. Instead, this snippet can be used to change poll frequency and it escapes almost all the exceptions (almost all).

```
def wait_until(predicate, timeout_seconds, period=0.25, show_log=True):
    """
    @summary Call repeatedly the predicate until it returns true or timeout_seconds passed.
    @param predicate: a condition, modelized as a callable,  that will valued either as True or False
    @param timeout_seconds: the timeout in second
    @param period: the time to sleep between 2 calls to predicate. Defaults to 0.25s.
    @return True if a call to predicate returned True before timeout_seconds passed, else False
    """
    if show_log:
        myLogger.logger.info("waiting until predicate is true for {end} seconds".format(end=timeout_seconds))
    ultimatum = time.time() + timeout_seconds
    while time.time() < ultimatum:
        myLogger.logger.debug("checking predicate for wait until : {spent} / {end}".format(spent=str(time.time() - (ultimatum - timeout_seconds)), end=timeout_seconds))
        try:
            if predicate():
                return True
            time.sleep(period)
        except Exception as e:
            myLogger.logger.warn("Exception found: {}".format(e))
    return False
```

Consequently, the predicate can be `lambda` that you pass which validates the state of the WebElement under question.

Comment: Thanks for participating! Is it a Python-based solution?..the question is about Protractor/WebDriverJS..

Comment: Yes, it is python based, but I guess the same idea can be applied in javascript.

Comment: Did something like this help you?