# How to validate a value before and after a promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, protractor

I am creating an end-to-end test for an Angular 1.5 application using Protractor. The application allows the user to upload a file to a backend Web API, by selecting a file using a standard `input type="file"` control and a `submit` button. I have a Controller that basically behaves like this:

```
function exampleController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.status = "";
    vm.buttonClickHandler = buttonClickHandler;

    function buttonClickHandler() {
        vm.status = "calling";
        service.makeAsyncCall()
               .then(function() {
                   vm.status = "success";
               }, function() {
                   vm.status = "error";
               });
    }
}
```

The `buttonClickHandler` is called when the user clicks the `submit` button.

How do I write an end-to-end test using Protractor that verifies that the status changes to "calling" when the user clicks the button, and then to "success" when the promise resolves?

In most of my attempts, I could verify that `vm.status` had been set to "success", **or** I could verify that it was set to "calling" if I set `ignoreSynchronization = true`, but the latter **only** works when I build in an artificial delay in my Web API backend call, otherwise the process was apparently too fast and the value would show "success".

Comment: Is there any indication on the UI side that `status` changes?

Comment: @alecxe yes, the UI correctly shows the `status` changes that I want. I just can't seem to capture them in an automated test.

Comment: Got it. Is there say an element with the status text or a loading spinner that we can check instead accessing the field in the controller? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, the status is simply bound to a div like so: `<div>{{vm.status}}</div>`, I access it in protractor using `element(by.binding("vm.status"))` which gives me the correct element.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather ugly, flaky and it's a bad practice but I would give a try anyway :)

```
it('click test', function () {
    $('button').click();

    browser.wait(function () {
        // Polls 'as fast as possible' until it evalutes to truthy value
        // This might be flaky if 'calling' status is shorter than
        // 1 polling interval (whose length can't be determined)
        return $('div_containing_status').getText().then(function (status) {
            return /calling/.test(status);
        });
    }, 10000);

    expect($('div_containing_status').getText()).toBe('calling');

    browser.wait(function () {
        return $('div_containing_status').getText().then(function (status) {
            return /success/.test(status);
        });
    }, 10000);

    expect($('div_containing_status').getText()).toBe('success');
});
```

**UPDATE:** edited info about polling based on @alecxe comment

Comment: Actually, [there is no explicit "poll frequency" for the `browser.wait()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704000/controlling-poll-frequency-of-browser-wait-fluent-wait). But I understand your idea and I wonder if this is gonna work reliably or not. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder where does the 500ms info come from :). I always thought it's 500ms but I just tested it and browser.wait() does indeed poll rather infrequently: 23:15:18.976 INFO - Executing: [get current url])
23:15:18.990 INFO - Done: [get current url]
23:15:18.997 INFO - Executing: [get current url])
23:15:19.006 INFO - Done: [get current url]
23:15:19.028 INFO - Executing: [get current url])
23:15:19.044 INFO - Done: [get current url]
23:15:19.074 INFO - Executing: [get current url])
23:15:20.384 INFO - Done: [get current url]

Comment: Yeah, 500 ms is the default poll frequency in other selenium language bindings, like Python or Java, though it's configurable there.

Comment: I'll test this on the actual code base next Monday, but I have a suspicion that the polling interval will be too long to capture the first "calling" status. The API call returns very quickly...