# What is default poll time for Explicit wait in Protractor API?

Tags: protractor

What is default poll time for Explicit wait in Protractor API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Default polling time is 500 ms.

I got this answer from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34377095/996075. I found your question and answer the same time I was looking for this answer.

Cheers!