# make selenium driver wait until elements style attribute has changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

As the title suggests need to wait for dynamically loaded material. The material shows when scrolling to the end of the page each time.

Currently trying to do this by the following:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='inf-loader']/span[1][contains(@style, 'display: inline-block')]")))
```

Is the xpath the problem here (not all that familiar)? It keeps timing out even though the display style does change when scrolling with selenium.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would wait for the `display` style to change to `inline-block` with a custom Expected Condition and use [`value_of_css_property()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.value_of_css_property):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class wait_for_display(object):
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            element = EC._find_element(driver, self.locator)
            return element.value_of_css_property("display") == "inline-block"
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False
```

Usage:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(wait_for_display((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='inf-loader']/span[1]")))
```

---

You may also try to [tweak the poll frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727340/javas-fluentwait-in-python) to make it check the condition more often:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5, poll_frequency=0.1)  # default frequency is 0.5
```