# Unable to click a search drop down box

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to wait for the search drop down box to appear before clicking on it on https://amazon.com using the following snippet of code.

```
search_dropdown_box = WebDriverWait(chrome_browser,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"searchDropdownBox")))
```

Despite this however, the snippet of code never seems to work, it always ends up failing with the following exception.

```
  File "C:/Users/DHIWAKAR-PC/PycharmProjects/AlationProject/assignment.py", line 18, in <module>
    search_dropdown_box = WebDriverWait(chrome_browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"searchDropdownBox")))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Is there something wrong with how I'm using the expected condition or is there some better expected condition that I can make use of ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to wait for an element that is invisible and not clickable until the `All` drop down is clicked. I mean, the locator that you are trying to click will become visible or clickable after clicking on the `All` drop down and you are using the wrong locator here.

Try to use `//div[@id='nav-search-dropdown-card']/div` as xpath, so that you can identify the `All` drop down button and can click on it.

If you want to select options from the drop down then you need to use `searchDropdownBox` as id after clicking on the `All` drop down.

Try the below code:

```
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/')
search_dropdown_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='nav-search-dropdown-card']/div")))
search_dropdown_box.click()
```

If you want to select any option from the drop down after clicking on `All`, then you can use the python's `Select` like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver path')
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/')
search_dropdown_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='nav-search-dropdown-card']/div")))
search_dropdown_box.click()

options = driver.find_element_by_id('searchDropdownBox')
select = Select(options)
select.select_by_visible_text('Baby')
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Couldn't have explained it better :), so the searchDropDownBox is basically an identifier for the drop down list, which isn't visible by default when the page is loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use ***element_to_be_clickable***

```html
search_dropdown_box = WebDriverWait(chrome_browser,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"searchDropdownBox")))
```

See https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions

Comment: Same exception again :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in Java, which was solved using the fluent wait.

For pyton, refer to this link:
[Java's FluentWait in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727340/javas-fluentwait-in-python)

you will need to add TimeoutException in ignored_exceptions list.

Comment: I added the exception to the list but it still manages to raise that exception.