# Selenium doesn't recognize class in LinkedIn

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I'm trying to build a selenium bot just as an excercise to interact with python.

I'm trying to list all the job announces on the first page.
I found out that each of the announce as the same class
[image]

`disabled ember-view job-card-container__link job-card-list__title`
But when I try to collect the datas using `find_elements_by_class_name`, Python returns just an empty list.
Do you know why?
Could you help me solving this? I don't know what I'm missing

Comment: when a css class name is separated by spaces it means there is more than one style associated with it.  (The DOM will have many... so "disabled", "ember-view" and "ember-view job-card-container__link job-card-list__title")

Comment: better to use an ID rather than a css class name.  Classes are used by many components, ID's should be unique.... so target the "data-control-id", or "id" attribute(s).

Comment: And how do I target the data control I'd?

Comment: use XPATH of "//a[@id='ember220']" or "//a[@data-control-id='PDV...']"

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the elements in LinkedIn do not load properly if you don't scroll down the page slowly. See [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69485558/12865727) that I used on LinkedIn Bot.